# Left align block of equations

Tags: latex

I want to left align a block of equations. The equations in the block itself are aligned, but that's not related at all to my question! I want to left align the equations rather than have them centered all the time, because it looks dumb with narrow centered equations.

Example, I want to left align this

```
\begin{align*}
    |\vec a| &= \sqrt{3^{2}+1^{2}} = \sqrt{10} \\
    |\vec b| &= \sqrt{1^{2}+23^{2}} = \sqrt{530} \\ 
    \cos v &= \frac{26}{\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{530}} \\
    v &= \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{26}{\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{530}}\right) \\
    v &= \uuline{69.08...\degree}
\end{align*}
```

but also this

```
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x
\end{align*}
```

How is this done? If it's even possible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try to use the `fleqn` document class option.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
```

(See also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics for a list of other options.)

Answer (score 47):

You can use `\begin{flalign}`, like the example bellow:

```
\begin{flalign}
    &f(x) = -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x&
\end{flalign}
```

Comment: This produces an error message: `LaTeX Error: Environment flalign undefined.`

Comment: @Maryam This is aligning the equations to right. What about aligning the equations to the left?

Comment: To align to the left you should place both `&` at the end of the equation, such as `f(x) = -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x&&`

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
\begin{flalign*}
    &|\vec a| = \sqrt{3^{2}+1^{2}} = \sqrt{10} & \\
    &|\vec b| = \sqrt{1^{2}+23^{2}} = \sqrt{530} &\\ 
    &\cos v = \frac{26}{\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{530}} &\\
    &v = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{26}{\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{530}}\right) &\\
\end{flalign*}
```

The `&` sign separates two columns, so an `&` at the beginning of a line means that the line starts with a blank column.

Answer (score 15):

The `fleqn` option in the document class will apply left aligning setting in all equations of the document. You can instead use `\begin{flalign}`. This will align only the desired equations.

Comment: Hello. I came across this post when looking for help with a similar issue, and I thank you for the info. However, when I used flalign, there was a huge gap between the equation and the equal sign. Do you know of a way to keep it ALL at the left?