# Left align a block of equations inside a proof using LaTeX

Tags: alignment, latex

I am suffering with this LaTeX document. **I am trying to left align the block of equations inside a proof.** There is a famous question about this on stack overflow:

[Left align block of equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632628/left-align-block-of-equations)

However, I tried using `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}`. It didn't work. I also tried using  `\begin{flalign}`, it didn't work.

**The math in my text looks ugly. I wish it was centralized or left aligned.**

That's how it looks:
[appearance of the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaTl8.png)

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\graphicspath{{images/}}


\begin{document}

\newpage


\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    \text{Seja: } \gamma(t) = (r \cos t,r\sin t, a\sin t + b\cos t +c)  \\
    \text{Primeira derivada: }\gamma'(t) = (-r\sin t,r\cos t,   a\cos t - b\sin t)  \\
    \text{Segunda derivada: }\gamma''(t) = (-r\cos t,-r\sin t,    -a\sin t - b\cos t)  \\
    \text{Terceira derivada: }\gamma'''(t) = (r\sin t,-r\cos t, -a\cos t + b\sin t)  \\
    \text{A torção pode ser expressa por: }\tau  = {{\left(   {r' \times r''} \right) \cdot r'''} \over {\left\| {r' \times r''} \right\|^2}}\\
    \text{A fórmula acima não exige que a curva esteja      parametrizada pelo cumprimento   de arco} \\
    \text{Desenvolvendo os cálculos do numerador}  \\
    \text{O produto vetorial das duas primeiras derivadas é:  } {\gamma'(t) \times \gamma''(t)= (-rb, -  ra, r²)}\\
    \text{O produto escalar é o produto vetorial vezes a   terceira derivada: } \\
    (-rb, -ra, r²)\cdot \gamma'''(t)  \\
    (-rb, -ra, r²)\cdot (r\sin t,-r\cos t, -a\cos t + b\sin t)   = 0 \\
    \text{O numerador é zero. Logo, a torção é zero. } \\
    \tau = 0 \\
    \text{Se a torção é zero, a curva é plana.} 
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
```

Comment: there is a stack exchange site devoted to answering questions about LaTeX, tex.stackexchange.com, you may get better results asking there.

Comment: @MMAdams, ok, thanks. I was not aware of that!

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: [Left align a block of equations inside a proof using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406801/5764)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a cross-network duplicate has already been posted on the appropriate site TeX.SE: [Left align a block of equations inside a proof using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406801/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer:

*Align expects a two-part entry (or multiples of two parts) on each line, with the first part right-aligned and the second part (usually after a sign of relation) left-aligned. the alignment point is marked by &. you haven't entered any alignment points. if you place a & before each line, all the lines will be aligned on the left.*

```
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
  &  \text{Seja: } \gamma(t) =  (r \cos t,r\sin t, a\sin t + b\cos t +c)  \\
   & \text{Primeira derivada: }\gamma'(t) = (-r\sin t,r\cos t,   a\cos t - b\sin t)  \\
   & \text{Segunda derivada: }\gamma''(t) = (-r\cos t,-r\sin t,    -a\sin t - b\cos t)  \\
   & \text{Terceira derivada: }\gamma'''(t) = (r\sin t,-r\cos t, -a\cos t + b\sin t)  \\
   & \text{A torção pode ser expressa por: }\tau  = {{\left(   {r' \times r''} \right) \cdot r'''} \over {\left\| {r' \times r''} \right\|^2}}\\
   & \text{A fórmula acima não exige que a curva esteja      parametrizada pelo cumprimento   de arco} \\
   & \text{Desenvolvendo os cálculos do numerador}  \\
   & \text{O produto vetorial das duas primeiras derivadas é:  } {\gamma'(t) \times \gamma''(t)= (-rb, -  ra, r²)}\\
   & \text{O produto escalar é o produto vetorial vezes a   terceira derivada: } \\
   & (-rb, -ra, r²)\cdot \gamma'''(t)  \\
   & (-rb, -ra, r²)\cdot (r\sin t,-r\cos t, -a\cos t + b\sin t)   = 0 \\
   & \text{O numerador é zero. Logo, a torção é zero. } \\
   & \tau = 0 \\
   & \text{Se a torção é zero, a curva é plana.} 
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put an & before each = sign to get the alignment at the equal signs.

Of course you can align how you prefer. Every line is aligned at the position where you place the &

Comment: if I do     \text{Seja: } \gamma(t) & =  (r \cos t,r\sin t, a\sin t + b\cos t +c)  \\ the goes extremely to the right... Quite the opposite of what I want. If i put the & sing at the begginin of the phrase this also happens...

Comment: You need to do this for all lines.